# How can I work around this bug in Java 8?

Tags: java, maven, compiler-errors

I'm writing an application for a while now and after some changes today I got this error when I was trying to `mvn clean install`:

```
An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.8.0_31). Please file a bug at the Java Developer Connection (http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport)  after checking the Bug Parade for duplicates. Include your program and the following diag nostic in your report.  Thank you. java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types.isConvertible(Types.java:290)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Check.assertConvertible(Check.java:922)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Check.checkMethod(Check.java:876)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.checkMethod(Attr.java:3838)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.checkIdInternal(Attr.java:3615)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.checkMethodIdInternal(Attr.java:3522)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.checkMethodId(Attr.java:3501)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.checkId(Attr.java:3488)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:3370)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:1897)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:607)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:1843)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1465)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:607)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribExpr(Attr.java:649)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitVarDef(Attr.java:1093)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCVariableDecl.accept(JCTree.java:852)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:607)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribStat(Attr.java:676)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribStats(Attr.java:692)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.DeferredAttr$DeferredAttrNode$StructuralStuckChecker.canLambdaBodyCompleteNormally(DeferredAttr.java:704)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.DeferredAttr$DeferredAttrNode$StructuralStuckChecker.visitLambda(DeferredAttr.java:652)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCLambda.accept(JCTree.java:1624)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.DeferredAttr$DeferredAttrNode$StructuralStuckChecker.complete(DeferredAttr.java:605)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.DeferredAttr$DeferredType.check(DeferredAttr.java:245)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.DeferredAttr$DeferredType.access$000(DeferredAttr.java:132)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.DeferredAttr$DeferredAttrNode.process(DeferredAttr.java:554)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.DeferredAttr$DeferredAttrContext.complete(DeferredAttr.java:479)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.rawInstantiate(Resolve.java:578)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.selectBest(Resolve.java:1431)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMethodInScope(Resolve.java:1618)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMethod(Resolve.java:1689)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMethod(Resolve.java:1662)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findConstructor(Resolve.java:2545)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve$11.doLookup(Resolve.java:2514)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve$BasicLookupHelper.lookup(Resolve.java:3074)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.lookupMethod(Resolve.java:3325)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.resolveConstructor(Resolve.java:2511)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.resolveConstructor(Resolve.java:2502)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitNewClass(Attr.java:2097)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCNewClass.accept(JCTree.java:1516)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:607)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribExpr(Attr.java:649)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitVarDef(Attr.java:1093)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCVariableDecl.accept(JCTree.java:852)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:607)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribStat(Attr.java:676)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribClassBody(Attr.java:4342)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribClass(Attr.java:4252)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribClass(Attr.java:4181)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attrib(Attr.java:4156)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.attribute(JavaCompiler.java:1248)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile2(JavaCompiler.java:901)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:860)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:523)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall(JavacTaskImpl.java:129)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:138)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavaxToolsCompiler.compileInProcess(JavaxToolsCompiler.java:126)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.performCompile(JavacCompiler.java:169)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:785)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:129)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:347)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:154)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:582)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356) [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------- [ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : [INFO]
------------------------------------------------------------- [ERROR] An unknown compilation problem occurred [INFO] 1 error [INFO]
------------------------------------------------------------- [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
```

I've never seen something like this before. How can I work around this?

Comment: It's *definitely* a bug in Java 8.

Comment: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8056038

Comment: Is there a specific reason you can't use Java 7 or Java 6 for this?

Comment: My program uses Java 8 features a lot (lambdas and streams for example).

Comment: Identify the change that caused the problem and undo it, or upgrade to one of the releases mentioned at the top of https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8044546

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line which caused the problem:

```
int count = possibleCards.stream().reduce(0,
 (cnt, c) -> cnt += (c.getTags().contains(tag) ? 1 : 0),
 (cnt1, cnt2) -> cnt1 + cnt2);
```

This line of code was supposed to count all card objects which had a specific tag.
The bug is reproducible. More details can be found here: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8056038?page=com.atlassian.streams.streams-jira-plugin:activity-stream-issue-tab

Answer (score 1):

Builds of Java 8 older than u25 on some platforms and u31 on others generally have oddball issues where lambdas and unboxing might not play nice together.  The workaround may be to explicitly infer some of the lambda types where unboxing may occur, such as:

```
(Integer count, c) -> count += c.getTags().contains(tag) ? 1 : 0)
```

But in this specific scenario, you might be able to avoid the issue entirely by using a combination of `mapToInt()` and `sum()` so that there is clearly no unboxing shenanigans going on.

The issue is supposed to be fixed in u40, but as of the writing of this answer, is not released.